# Order of operations for accessing the memory address of a list item?

Tags: c

Suppose I had an extremely basic C code that simply printed the memory address of an element inside the list such as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%x", &data[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

**What is the order of operations for the `&data[2]` call?**

I am finding it hard to visually see because `data[2]` returns a number, and getting the memory address of a number "3" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Technically that `printf` call will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you have a mismatching format specifier and type. To print a pointer you should use `"%p"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C the syntax `array[index]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(array + index)` and the address-of operator `&array[index]` can be rewritten as just `(array + index)`, which is what you're taking the address of with the statement `&data[2]`. You aren't getting the address of the *value at `data[2]`* (i.e. 3); you're getting the address of `(data + 2)`.

Try this:

```
int data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
printf("%p\n", (void *)&data[2]);
printf("%p\n", (void *)(data + 2));
```

You will see the same address on both lines.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an array, the compiler will reserve memory for it, and you can store values in that memory.

What is returned by e.g. `&data[2]` is not a pointer to the integer `3` but a pointer to the array element where you have opted to store the integer value `3`.

An array like yours look like this in memory

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| data[0] | data[1] | data[2] | data[3] | data[4] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The exact values stored in each element is kind of irrelevant if all you want is a pointer to an element.